# Why guava doesn't trim |

Tags: java, guava

Could someone explain me why the following code:

```
Splitter.on("\n").trimResults(CharMatcher.is('|')).trimResults().split("|a\nb|\nc|")
```

returns

```
[|a,b|,c|]
```

instead of

```
[a,b,c]
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: `CharMatcher` does not use regexes; escapes are unnecessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second `trimResults` overrides the first.

You want

```
Splitter.on("\n").trimResults(CharMatcher.is('|')).split("|a\nb|\nc|")
```

or maybe

```
Splitter.on("\n")
    .trimResults(CharMatcher.is('|').or(CharMatcher.WHITESPACE))
    .split("|a\nb|\nc|")
```

to get rid of both.